# How to transform while loop into foreach loop in the context of using fopen and fgetcsv functions?

Tags: php, foreach

This is the standard code on php.net:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Let's assume that test.csv has 3 rows with:

```
cell11,cell12,cell13
cell21,cell22,cell23
cell31,cell32,cell33
```

Is it possible to use a foreach loop instead of the while used here and still get the values inside test.csv, for further use?

The code above gives this result:

```
3 fields in line 1: 
cell11
cell12
cell13
3 fields in line 2: 
cell21
cell22
cell23
3 fields in line 3: 
cell31
cell32
cell33
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
//    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
//        $num = count($data);
//        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
//        $row++;
//        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
//            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
//        }
//    }
    foreach(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) as $field){
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

And the result:

```
3 fields in line 1: 
cell11
cell12
cell13
3 fields in line 2: 
cell11
cell12
cell13
3 fields in line 3: 
cell11
cell12
cell13
```

Comment: This is something you can easily try yourself. Why do you ask this here?

Comment: Well, because I tried and couldn't solve it, obviously. Thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: Than show what you tried exactly because you should have the answer already, but it probably needs some explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
foreach(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) as $field){ ...
```

Passes the data from `fgetcsv` to the new variable `$data` which doesn't make sense in this case. You can just write this:

```
foreach (fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",") as $field) { …
```

But to explain why foreach doesn't work:

As `fget` (and thus `fgetcsv`) is a function it does not work as an array, it just returns one, namely the next line in the file.

The foreach example above just gets the first line from that function and iterates over it. This means you iterate over each column of the first line.